# cannot find virtual device on android studio 3 windows 10

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am relatively new to Android development and i recently downloaded Android Studio on my Windows 10 machine. But i am facing some problems. When i create a new project, in the **activity_main.xml** design tab I cannot see any virtual device. All i see is a message that says ***Design Editor unavailable until successful build***. When I click on build,I don't see any message regarding the build in the IDE log. I have the AVD manager installed and i have also created a virtual device. 
Also when i edit the RUN configuration, it asks me to select a module but in the drop down window it says **no module**

Comment: Can you add screenshot with error?

Comment: unfortunately i can't. Stack overflow says I cannot embed a picture yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Just update your repositories by clicking on install missing platforms and sync project, i hope that will help **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZHpF.png)

Comment: This contribution, in its current conversational style, would work better as a comment.